# Android: Access content:// file from intent

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-intent, android-contentprovider

In my Android App I authorise the user to share a zip-file with my application (in most cases the user will only use Dropbox for sharing).

So I tried for hours to figure out how to access the content:// file my App is receiving from Dropbox.

I'm using this code:

```
Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
Uri dataUri = intent.getData();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if(dataUri != null){
  String dataUriString = dataUri.toString();
  File rootDataDir = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir();
  if(unzipFile(dataUriString, rootDataDir.toString())){
     //true
  }else{
     //false
  }
  bundle.putString("receive_data", dataUri.toString());
}
return bundle;
```

In dataUriString we have something like:

> "content://com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/...contenID.."

But if I try to access the file as a normal it won't work:

```
public boolean unzipFile(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        try{
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            File file = new File(inputPath);
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
            while(zipEntry != null){
                String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
                File newFile = new File(outputPath+ "/import/" + fileName);
                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile, false)){
                    int len;
                    while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                }
                zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
            }
            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();
            return true;
        }catch(IOException err){
            return false;
        }
    }


    private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ReactNative", "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + e.toString());
            return "";
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

So how do I have to work/handle content:// files?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

> But if I try to access the file as a normal it won't work

That is because it is not a file. Similarly, [Android: Access content:// file from intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809549/android-access-content-file-from-intent) is not a file.

> So how do I have to work/handle content:// files?

Use `ContentResolver` (from `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`) and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: I've seen you answer this question multiple times. I still haven't found one example on how to achieve this. Can you please provide a example? Lets say i have a `MediaPlayer` and I need to pass it a path/uri, how would I go about doing that when the file is selected from Dropbox?

Comment: @HB.: "how would I go about doing that when the file is selected from Dropbox?" -- I do not know what API you are using and what you wind up with when the user selects something. If you get a `content://` `Uri` from Dropbox, you might be able to use that directly. Otherwise, open a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Use something from Dropbox to get an `InputStream` on the Dropbox content. Copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`. Then, you can use your file copy for things that need a file.

Comment: "If you get a `content://` `Uri` from Dropbox, you might be able to use that directly" can you please elaborate on that? My `Uri` is similar to this question `content://com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/`

Comment: @HB.: Try passing that to `setDataSource()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer?hl=en#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)

Comment: Can you please check if what I'm currently doing is correct? I added comments to explain what I did - Currently the video is playing as expected, I just want to make sure if what I'n doing is correct - https://pastebin.com/pm26UJei

Comment: @HB.: That approach is guaranteed to work (as much as anything is guaranteed in Android...). You could close the `Cursor` sooner, as you don't need it after `String filename = cursor.getString(nameIndex);`. The costs of this approach are the time to make the copy and the space consumed by the copy (until you delete the copy). Ideally, Dropbox would allow their `Uri` to be used by `setDataSource()` or have some other means for you to use their content directly in `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Ok awesome. Thank for taking the time to help out.